# Function Call in Expression Binding in OpenUI5/SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, templates, binding, sapui5

Problem is to print out the current year by using [expression binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html) that was introduced with 1.28.

Expression Binding is capable of executing global accessible JS Functions.

Goal: Execute (new Date()).getFullYear() in expression binding

- In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gf6k2ay1/24/) the first attempt is to execute a global string {:=Math.PI} => **works**
- Second attempt is to define a global function `window.temp = function() {return 'test'};` and to execute it via `<Text text="{:=temp()}" />` => **fail**
- Goal `<Input value="{:=(new Date()).getFullYear()}" />` breaks parser  and is in jsfiddle therefor outcommented.
  The Error Message is *Expected ) but instead saw Date at position 9 - {:=(new Date()).getFullYear()} sap.ui.base.ExpressionParser*

First question is: Why does the parser break? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Second question is: Even if the goal is not possible. Why is my second attempt also not working?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the parser breaks as it does not support the **new** operator. Your second example is not working as only functions which are available via global symbols can be used. The **window** object is not listed there.

Comment: Re "only functions which are available via global symbols can be used": 


Would be nice if that was documented.  I've spent ages on this before I found your answer.

Comment: Hi Peter, it is documented. From the documentation of syntax element function call: "You can use functions that are available via global symbols, such as Math.max(...) or isNaN(...)."

Comment: Hi matbtt, not to quibble about semantics but it doesn't have the word "only" as your answer did.  I guess it might seem like a reasonable thing to infer but honestly, I read that documentation before I went searching for the answer and got the impression it was more of a suggestion of how it could be used than a limitation.

Comment: Hi Peter, okay I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. As commenters have stated, function calls from global symbols are allowed, so an obvious hack would be:

On init:

```
Date.evilhack = (a => new Date(a));
```

And in the expression binding:

```
{= Date.evilhack(${something}).getFullYear() }
```

If anyone has a better idea, please share!
I know there are custom formatters, but I'm looking for a minimal, hopefully clean, solution.